How can I write A2:A and not get any results for empty cells
I'd like to ask a follow-up question to How to dynamically return values horizontally in Google Sheets
here is my formula:
=MAP(UNIQUE(AD2:AD100), LAMBDA(account, {account, TRANSPOSE(FILTER(HYPERLINK(AE2:AE100, "️"), AD2:AD100 = account))}))

I noticed that if I dont specify exact range (e.g A2:A instead of A2:A8), it would say "Result was not automatically expanded, please insert more columns (643)." and it would add a lot of columns. If I change it to A2:A100, it works better, but it would add a lot of results for an empty cell. how can I solve these 2 problems so I can write A2:A and not get any results for empty cells?


When the value in AD2:AD is blank, all other rows where that column is blank will match, resulting in a large array. You can weed blank cells out like this:
    ifna(filter(hyperlink(AE2:AE100, "️"), len(AD2:AD100), AD2:AD100 = account))

See ifna(), filter() and len().

ahhh, i use filter often but didnt think of this, thanks a lot! i know i can use iferror to get rid of the "No matches are found in FILTER evaluation." that comes at the end, but is there a way to avoid it without iferror?

You can use if(iserror()), but it is usually easier to use ifna().

okay thank you :)

You can also wrap your UNIQUE function in TOCOL with skip_blanks set to remove the single blank value:
=MAP(TOCOL(UNIQUE(A2:A),1), 
   LAMBDA(u, {u, 
     TOROW(FILTER(
       HYPERLINK(B2:B, "️"),
       A2:A=u))}))

TOCOL Function

so elegant thank you, i'll test it out in a bit

yep works perfectly, thanks for this! very short and easy
